# Load data from multiple columns in Joomla

Tags: php, sql, joomla3.0

I've been stuck with this problem. I have a form where the user will enter his/her input. Based on that input, a query is done to the database that will return matching results.I
t's fairly simple but couldn't find a way to do it.
I manage to load the data using loadResult().

But now since I want to load from multiple columns, loadResult() is a no go.

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$name = JRequest::getVar('name');
$query="SELECT username FROM jos_users WHERE name='$name'";
$db->setQuery($query);
echo $db->loadResult();
?>
```

That was my code when I was using loadResult(). No problem.

But now I want to load username and status from the query. How can I do that?

I tried putting in

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$name = JRequest::getVar('name');
$query="SELECT username, status FROM jos_users WHERE name='$name'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->loadObject($name);
echo "Username : $name->username";
echo "Status : $name->status";
?>
```

But returns an error.

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: The page cannot load and the error :Fatal error: Class '' not found in /home/iobaccom/public_html/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysql.php on line 425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is supposed to be like this. 
You have to store return value in a variable and then you can use it. But in your code you are trying to print value with the params send to loadObject method.

```
<?php 
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $name = JRequest::getVar('name');
    $query="SELECT username, status FROM jos_users WHERE id='$name'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadObject();
    echo "Username : $row->username";
    echo "Status : $row->status";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change:

```
$db->loadObject($name); 
echo "Username : $name->username";
echo "Status : $name->status";
```

to:

```
$row = $db->loadRowList();
echo "Username : ".$row['username'];
echo "Status :".$row['status'];
```

Comment: That resolved the error displayed. But it did not returned the matching results from the user input. Do I need to put the JRequest in the earlier line?

Comment: @user1867016 $row = null ? No, JRequest don`t change. Change in query "WHERE name='$name'" and you got need info )

Comment: @user1867016  in $query you compare id with name? Undertand? See your first example and second

Comment: Whoops. Im sorry that was my typo mistake. The actual code is WHERE name='$name' just like you said. What do you mean by $row=null?